# Parallax effect is slightly choppy when first loaded in UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, parallax

I am working on implementing a parallax effect for my UICollectionView.  The effect thankfully is working.  However, when I scroll the collection vertically for the very first time, there is a choppy effect that occurs.  This ONLY happens on the first scroll through of the list.  After that, the parallax effect is smooth while scrolling.

Below is my relevant code:

### MyViewController.swift:

```
extension FeedViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Scroll navigation bar animation
        let scrolledDown = scrollView.contentOffset.y > -self.topLayoutGuide.length
        let newAlpha:CGFloat = scrolledDown ? 0.65 : 0.00

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
            self.navBarBackground.alpha = newAlpha
        }

        // Parallax effect
        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() {
            updateParallaxCell(cell)
        }
    }

    func updateParallaxCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        if let myCell = cell as? MyCustomCell {
            myCell.updateParallaxEffect(collectionView, mainView: view)
        }
    }
}
```

### MyCustomCell.swift

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundImageOriginalOrigin = backgroundImage.frame.origin
    }

    func updateParallaxEffect(collectionView: UICollectionView, mainView view: UIView) {
        let convertedRect = collectionView.convertRect(self.frame, toView: view)  //frame of the cell within the coordinate system of the main view
        let distanceFromCenter = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) / 2 - CGRectGetMinY(convertedRect)  //y coordinate distance of the cell from the center of the main view
        let difference : CGFloat = 50.0  //maximum relative offset of the image within the cell
        let move = -difference / 4 + (distanceFromCenter / self.frame.size.height) * difference  // calculated relative offset of the image

        let y = self.backgroundImageOriginalOrigin.y + move // newly calculated Y coordinate of the image
        self.backgroundImage.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.backgroundImageOriginalOrigin.x, y) // adjusting the image view frame
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        updateParallaxEffect(collectionView, mainView: mainView)
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Run it through the time profiler in Instruments and see what's eating the CPU during that time period. I'm guessing something laying out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
UICollectionView().setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 1), animated: true)
UICollectionView().setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: false)
```